# Send Big File from One page to another in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a React App which have two pages in it wrapped in a react router now page one takes input of a pdf from user and now i need to preview this pdf on page 2 with some other content How can i send this pdf to page 2 from page 1? I was thinking to use redux or context API but it says it does not allows non serializable data , what other approach i can use to share this data among these two pages?

Here is the code of main app.jsx where react router exists :-

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Loader from './Components/Loading/Loading';

const Home = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Home/Home'));
const Analyser = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/ContractAnalyser/Analyser'));

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={(
              <React.Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                <Home />
              </React.Suspense>
          )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/Analyser"
            element={(
              <React.Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                <Analyser />
              </React.Suspense>
          )}
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the data in the real time using firebase maybe
then it will return a link for this file (pdf, picture, ...etc)

It's downloadable and free
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

You should be familiar with firebase (basic knowledge)

See this too,
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/299

Comment: or use any other service like AWS

Comment: THanks for this suggestion, but is a good idea from user's perspective where user simple uploaded the pdf and now we are first sending it to a database and downloading it again on another page? It will simple eat user's data and does not looks like a good idea to maintain a database just to share a file among a page which user inputs, let me know if I am wrong , its just what i think